# Checking a text file line by line and word by word python

Tags: python

I have a list of words Ex: Juice, Water, Lemonade
and a text file

```
Lemon Lemonade Mango Curd Doggy
Dafne Cord Water Color Lemon
Powder Doggy TV Juice
```

I need my python program to read each word and compare to "Juice, Water, Lemonade" and per each line print

```
Line 1: NotAccepted(Lemon) Accepted NotAccepted(Mango) NotAccepted(Curd) NotAccepted(Doggy)
Line 2:NotAccepted(Dafne) NotAccepted(Cord) Accepted NotAccepted(Color) NotAccepted(Lemon)
Line 3:NotAccepted(Powder) NotAccepted(Doggy) NotAccepted(TV) Accepted
```

My current program is printing

```
NotAccepted(Lemon)
Accepted
NotAccepted(Mango)
NotAccepted(Curd)
```

with my current code:
Which

```
lineas = archivo.readlines()

for linea in lineas:
    linea = linea.strip()
    lista = linea.split()
    for a in lista:
        if (a == "Mango"):
            print ("Aceptado", end="")
        else:
            print ("Denegado ("+ a + ")",end="")
```

Comment: Great list of words. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find out if each word on a line matches with your list of pre-determined words?

```
for line in text_file:
    for j in line.split(' '):
        if j=='Juice' or j=='Water' or j=='Lemonade':
            print('Accepted')
        else:
            print('Not accepted('+j+')')
```

should suffice - it'll break onto new lines every print but that's relatively easily to fix :)

Comment: How would I make it to print in same line ? like per Line

Comment: I got it, but if my list of Word is quite big like more than 20? will I have to do "OR" for each word?

Comment: An easy way would be to have something like a variable `word_list=['a','b'....']` and then check `if j in word_list`. For same line printing, you could - after `for line in text_file`, have `output=''`, and then instead of using `print`, use `output+=`

Comment: If I want to put that if it starts with an quotation mark, it is correct until the end of the quotation mark Ex:
Ramen Cord "Cardomologisticly correct" Rambo
NotCorrect(Ramen) NotCorrect(Cord) Correct NotCorrect(Rambo)

Comment: I dont understand your question

Comment: My program is about making an compiler, which will read a txt file and compare to a list of RESERVED words.